# django time field displays as none in admin panel

Tags: python, django

In the admin page I added the following code:

```
class StoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'domain', 'moderator', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    list_filter = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
    search_fields = ('title','moderator__username','moderator__first_name','moderator__last_name')
    fields = ('title','url','created_at','updated_at')
    readonly_fields = ('created_at','updated_at')
admin.site.register(Story, StoryAdmin)
```

Everything works just fine, except when I add a new story in the admin panel the `readonly_fields` in the template displays as `(none)`!

Comment: Can you show us the model code for `Story`?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design; from the [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) documentation:

> By default the admin shows all fields as editable. Any fields in this
>   option (which should be a list or tuple) will display its data as-is
>   and non-editable; **they are also excluded from the ModelForm used for
>   creating and editing.**

If you want your users not to edit fields, simply do not show them as part of the admin form, by removing them from the `fields` tuple.